# How do I compile Rust on MacOS, to be run on an AWS EC2 instance? "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, rust, compiler-errors, cross-compiling

**Problem**

I've written some fairly simple Rust code on a Macbook, to be deployed on an AWS EC2 instance but when I SCP the binary across and run it, I am met with "**bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error**"

**Mac Details**

- ProductName: macOS
- ProductVersion:  12.4
- BuildVersion:    21F79

**AWS Details**

- Instance type: t3.micro
- `uname -r`: 5.10.0-10-cloud-amd64

**Attempted Solution**

I understand that it's a mismatch between the architecture of my machine vs the EC2 machine and since the EC2 is Debian, I'm assumed that the target type I want is "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu", but running `cargo build --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` results in "error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
" with a very lengthy note.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've found to do a similar thing is use [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross). This is a cargo extension that will pull in all the dependencies needed to cross compile onto a different architecture. The command format is deliberately identical to cargo:

e.g.

```bash
cross build --release --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

You can find instructions to set it up on their wiki page: https://github.com/cross-rs/cross#installation

As for the actual error, I believe the problem with just setting the target in cargo is that rust will still depend on the installed libc which will be for the native architecture. `cross` gets round this by using docker images.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the target architecture is not arm-based.. AMD should require an x86_64 target.